# Background of layout doesn't appear to render correctly on Tablet device, while render perfectly on mobile phone

Tags: android, xml, tablet, tablayout

This is the xml of the background drawable. In phone render perfectly, in tablet didn't. This drawable was used for a background in tablayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="50dp"
        android:top="10dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#E3EBF2" />
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the "layer-list" it somehow failed to render on tablet, solution: remove the layer-list, put only shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#F2E3EBF2" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
</shape>
```